# Completely custom path with YII?

Tags: yii

I have various products with their own set paths. Eg:

1. electronics/mp3-players/sony-hg122
2. fitness/devices/gymboss

If want to be able to access URLs in this format. For example:

```
http://www.mysite.com/fitness/devices/gymboss
http://www.mysite.com/electronics/mp3-players/sony-hg122
```

My strategy was to override the "init" function of the SiteController in order to catch the paths and then direct it to my own implementation of a render function. However, this doesn't allow me to catch the path.

Am I going about it the wrong way? What would be the correct strategy to do this?

** EDIT **

I figure I have to make use of the [URL manager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url). But how do I dynamically add path formats if they are all custom in a database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eskimo's setup is a good solid approach for most Yii systems. However, for yours, I would suggest creating a custom UrlRule to query your database:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#using-custom-url-rule-classes

Note: the URL rules are parsed on every single Yii request, so be careful in there. If you aren't efficient, you can rapidly slow down your site. By default rules are cached (if you have a cache setup), but I don't know if that applies to dynamic DB rules (I would think not).

Comment: Dumb question, but in the example, where would you actually place the file? The new CarUrlRule class file?

Comment: Probably in your components folder

Comment: Okay, I got it.... its depends on --> 'class' => 'application.components.CarUrlRule', ... haha

Answer (score 1):

In your URL manager (*protected/config/main.php*), Set `urlFormat` to `path` (and toptionally set `showScriptName` to `false` (this hides the index.php part of the URL))

```
'urlManager' => array(
    'urlFormat' => 'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false,
```

Next, in your rules, you could setup something like:

```
catalogue/<category_url:.+>/<product_url:.+> => product/view,
```

So what this does is route and request with a structure like *catalogue/electronics/ipods* to the *ProductController actionView*. You can then access the `category_url` and `product_url` portions of the URL like so:

```
$_GET['category_url'];
$_GET['product_url'];
```

How this rule works is, any URL which starts with the word catalogue (directly after your domain name) which is followed by another word (`category_url`), and another word (`product_url`), will be directed to that controller/action.

You will notice that in my example I am preceding the category and product with the word catalogue. Obviously you could replace this with whatever you prefer or leave it out all together. The reason I have put it in is, consider the following URL:

```
http://mywebsite.com/site/about
```

If you left out the 'catalogue' portion of the URL and defined your rule only as:

```
<category_url:.+>/<product_url:.+> => product/view,
```

the URL Manager would see the site portion of the URL as the `category_url` value, and the about portion as the `product_url`. To prevent this you can either have the catalogue protion of the URL, or define rules for the non catalogue pages (ie; define a rule for *site/about*)

Rules are interpreted top to bottom, and only the first rule is matched. Obviously you can add as many rules as you need for as many different URL structures as you need.

I hope this gets you on the right path, feel free to comment with any questions or clarifications you need